`repo_type` argument if needed
Now trying to run a python script, loading a model from hugging face.
In the terminal it gives an error:
huggingface_hub.errors.HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': 'Jzuluaga/accent-id-commonaccent_ecapa/data'. Use `repo_type` argument if needed.

Sure that there is no typo in the name of model.
Im sure as well that the model is public, but have no idea why it is not letting me in.

There's an extra /data at the end of Jzuluaga/accent-id-commonaccent_ecapa/data - try Jzuluaga/accent-id-commonaccent_ecapa as the message implies.
